# Magento2 - controller redirect using plugins

Tags: magento2.2, plugin, dependency-injection

Doing url redirects is an easy thing rewriting a controller class, as `$this->resultRedirectFactory` is accessible as it is one of default injected objects

But, can we use this in plugins? I've been trying different ways, with no success

For instance... let's say I want to write plugin for **\Magento\Multishipping\Controller\Checkout\Addresses** controller `execute()` method, ignoring all logic & just redirecting to checkout/cart

Can someone provide how we could do this in a plugin with the 3 possible approaches (`before`, `around` & `after`)? Full code of the plugin class would be great, as my main problem is I haven't understand yet about how plugin parameters work

**UPDATE**

Not 100% sure, but I believe I tried same code as [kirby](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/17129/kirby) solution yesterday, but using `before` plugin and saw constructor errors in frontend...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plugin type depends on what you need.
I guess, "after" and "around" could work for you.

The manual about plugins is here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

I suppose, you may declare a redirect factory and use it.

Let's say you will have static redirection. Your code could look like this:

```
namespace My\Module\Controller\Some;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Multishipping\Controller\Checkout\Addresses as AddressesAction;

class AddressesActionPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $context->getResultRedirectFactory();
    }

    /**
     * Plugin method
     */
    public function aroundExecute(AddressesAction $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        // here, maybe do some logic with $subject - action-controller instance

        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()
            ->setPath(
                'some/where/else',
                [
                    'my-param' => 123,
                ]
            );
    }
}
```

Please note, I haven't tested this code. Feel free to change it if there are some mistakes.

Comment: I will try this & give you feedback

Comment: It is working ;)

Comment: Cool! I was glad to help! ;)